# Logout form within Bootstrap navbar dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap3 navbar with a dropdown menu.

I want my "logout" form inside that dropdown. It is not a visible form, just a logout button within a form.

I tried this:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">

        <!-- this dropdown menu item looks right -->
        <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>

        <!-- this dropdown menu item (a logout form) does not -->
        <li><form action="/logout" method="post"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Log off</button></form></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But it is not styled properly.

How do I make it match normal dropdown links? I hope I don't need to manually tweak the css, and that there's a built in way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this [Sample [UPDATED]](https://jsfiddle.net/leonardoaraujocosta/kga54crn/1/)

```css
.btn-logout {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px 20px !important;
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
          </div>

          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <form>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link btn-logout">Logout</button>
                    </form>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have helped you in some way

Comment: It says "Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery" ?

Comment: @grokky Look at my Sample link at the beginning of the answer, there's example is correct.

Comment: @grokkysorry, my jsFiddle is broken. I will adjust and send you a new one.

Comment: @grokky Ready. I just added a new link Sample. Anything, just let me know :)

Comment: The css works, thanks. Pity it's not built in to Bootstrap. It targets the link using `>a` which is the cause of the problem.

Comment: @grokky I made the necessary changes, and now I think it's all working. :)

Answer (score 4):

That will not really work, but you can create the logout-form somewhere else:

```
<form id="logout-form" style="display:none" action="/logout" method="POST"></form>
```

and when the user clicks on `logout` you just call

```
document.getElementById("logout-form").submit();
```

in Javascript or you set

```
onclick="document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"
```

Comment: That would work, but I'd rather avoid script for something so simple. If no one else knows how, I'll just custom style the thing. Your way works though, so thanks.

Comment: @grokky Javascript is a standard, so you can use them for **whatever you like** to :)

Comment: @timmyRS The problem with using JavaScript here is that anyone who has JavaScript disabled won't be able to log out. For some, that may not be an issue. But most will recommend that your site still functions without JavaScript. Although JavaScript SPAs are becoming more and more common, so it's likely less and less of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this just give link to .java/servlet file.

```
<li><a href="Logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Logout</a></li>
```

Comment: In what way does this help?